# Should I use IMemoryCache or a custom GlobalCache for my .Net Core web app?

Tags: c#, caching, blazor-server-side

I'm just about to migrate some of my C# WinForms code to some Blazor server-side application (using .Net Core).

In my Winforms code, I've implemented my own Global Cache manager class that

- loads all items into memory from the database when they're first queried
- uses syncing to refresh only those items from database that changed on demande
- prevents writing obsolete data to the database (using some kind of optimistic lock procedure).

Memory usage shows this is perfectly fine for the data size I have to manage. Performance is great overall, except of course when I first load the data.

My initial idea was to register a Singleton service that would fetch data once and handle syncing as I did in the WinForms app.

As I'm not quite familiar with the web service world, I did some research and I came accross the `IMemoryCache` which seems in fact quite similar.

So to the question : I know that I **have to** use some kind of caching as loading all elements every time will kill performance. Is there some specific reason I should **NOT** use my global cache manager approach and move towards `IMemoryCache` or any other method (suggestions are more than welcome).